# Text overflowing in site wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I need to edit the mobile version of this site by centering the text in all of the sections but it's not working for some of them.

This is the link: othodesign.com

This is the code for the last section I tried to use to center:

```
.categories .module-title.font-alt.home-prod-title {
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    padding: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.categories .module-subtitle.font-serif.home-prod-subtitle {
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .01px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

This is the code for the section with a picture and some text over it (the one with the girl on top of a car) :

```
.categories .module-title.font-alt.home-prod-title {
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    padding: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.categories .module-subtitle.font-serif.home-prod-subtitle {
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .01px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

This is in WordPress and I'm using a theme that doesn't allow me to delete any CSS, I'm using a plugin that allows me to add some CSS code in.

Comment: please share your link

Comment: yes the link is othodesign.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `white-space: nowrap;` on `.section-overlay-layer .module-title`.
Remove it, or add `white-space: normal;` for the mobile version.

Comment: Can you put my solution online please?
You can also remove `word-break: break-all !important;`